# using pyinstaller for multiple files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have following file structure from a python project:

```
├───gui
│       gui.py
│       gui.ui
│
├───resources
│   │   res.py
│   │   res.qrc
│   │   res_rc
│   │
│   ├───css
│   │       style.qss
│   │
│   ├───icons
│   │       test.png
│   │
│   └───settings
│           settings.ini
│
└───source
    │   main.py
    │
    ├───manager0
    │       test0.py
    │
    ├───manager1
    │       test1.py
    │
    └───manager2
            test2.py
```

The `main.py` in the `source` folder, which includes the other dependent `.py` files as following:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

sys.path.append('../project/resources')
from resources import project

from source.manager0.test0 import *
from source.manager1.test1 import *
from source.manager2.test2 import *
...
```

I want to create an `.exe` file using the pyinstaller and for that I have tried following command:

```
C:\Users\us\proejct\source> pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Or adding the paths using:

```
C:\Users\us\proejct\source> pyinstaller main.py --paths ..\resources\ --paths ..\source\
```

In both cases an `.exe` file is created. But if it is started, I get the errors like:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative to `main.py`, folder `../project` does not exist, so line `sys.path.append('../project/resources')` is useless. The `resources` folder is available at the path `../resources`, so to be able to import from it you should write

```py
sys.path.append('..')
```

The `manager0,1,2` folders are in the same folder as `main.py`, so you can write

```py
from manager0.test0 import *
from manager1.test1 import *
from manager2.test2 import *
```

Also I noticed that there is no `project` folder in the `resources` folder, is it a typo? So, `from resources import project` will always fails. If you want to import `resources/res.py`, you can write

```py
from resources import res
```

Note that this import must be plased **after** `sys.path.append` call.

After these changes you can compile `main.py` with this command:

```bash
pyinstaller --onefile main.py --paths ..
```